# Openbay Pro module category sync not working

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, opencart

I am using the Opencart template platform and the Openbay Pro extension module to link my Ebay Store with my Online Ecommerce store. I use a mysql database.

When I try to sync the categories from Ebay with my store I get a java script error that says: "Error connecting to the server."

I have tried using the support on both the Openbay Pro site and my own server host and they just keep tossing the ball back and forth between them.

I have tried changing the htaccess file and the php.ini file to increase the mysql database time outs and file size limits.

If anyone else has any suggestions or has already gone thru this and solved it I would sure appreciate the help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar timeout problem - the server company had to fix it i dont know what they did but sent them the questions page here http://help.welfordmedia.co.uk/kb/openbay-pro/ebay/syncronise and it worked after.